# PostBackUrl in RadPanelBar Telerik

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Greetings everyone.. i would just like to ask.. how do i assign a postback url in my radpanel items in my master page

Eventually i have a MasterPage wherein i construct my radpanelbar.. and i have this Item Quiz with a child name Create

What i want to achieve is when i hit the button Create in my radpanelbar it will make a

```
PostBackUrl="CategoryCreate.aspx?Quiz=True"
```

please show me how to do this and another question how do i manipulate the Create child in my RadPanelBar.. i have started this code shown below.. but i don't know what to do next to achieve my goal..

```
    Protected Sub RadPanelBar1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RadPanelBarEventArgs)

    Dim instance As RadPanelBar
    instance.PostBackUrl = "CategoryCreate.aspx?Quiz=True"

    '//// i don't know how to pass it to child in my radpanelbar help
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are some knowledgeable folks around here about specific Telerik RAD controls, you might be better off re-posting your question on the Telerik forums specific to the RAD controls.  You will probably get much better assistance there direct from Telerik.  The link for those support forums is below:

**Telerik Forums:**
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx